# Is an X Window System older than release 10 available online?

Tags: history, graphics, software, unix

I'm looking for any copy of the X Window System older than release 10.

- The oldest on x.org is X10R3.
- Bob Scheifler doesn't have anything.
- Jim Gettys may have something, but has yet to retrieve it from an old hard disk.
- Keith Packard doesn't have anything older than X10.

Also any copy of W.  I have checked with Paul Asente, Brian Reid, and Chris Kent; they don't have anything.

Comment: Technically strictly speaking I don't think this is a Stack Exchangey question, but it's otherwise on topic, and it's answerable. Unless and until it causes problems in practice, I think we should give it a chance.

Comment: That would be X-1, right?  First there was X-0, then X-1, then X-10, now X-11.   (I don't know why they never got to X-100 - how could it be that from _1987_ to ... I don't know, Wayland? - there was no need for a significant upgrade to the protocol?)

Comment: @davidbak see [this previous answer on the topic](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/a/3056/79).

Comment: Really embarrassed that I have to explain this (admittedly stupid) joke to you , but: [hint](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_number#Binary_counting)

Comment: @davidbak yes, but I thought that despite that, “there was no need for a significant upgrade to the protocol?” was a genuine question.

Comment: @wizzwizz4 note that different sites have different policies around list questions, subjective questions, etc

Comment: @davidbak this happens to a lot of software. It seems that after X11 the core was good enough and usage was widespread enough that further improvements were better to be made as compatible optional extensions rather than whole new incompatible versions. (Also, there were a couple of failed Wayland-likes before Wayland. One might call it NotX3)